# JQuery doesn't apply to elements created after page load

Tags: jquery

If I call this:

```
$(".month-selector").change(function(){
    setStones();
});
```

Inside the`$(document).ready()` it does not apply to elements that are created later. I also tried calling the above code after creating them like so:

```
$("#month-selectors").html(month_selectors);

$(".month-selector").change(function(){
    setStones();
});
```

It still doesn't work. However, If I create a static one, it works.

How can I apply this to the elements when I create them after the page loads?

Comment: A side note... You don't need the `function(){ setStones(); }`, you could just pass the `setStones` function as the event handler: `$(".month-selector").change(setStones)`

Comment: @gnarf, thanks! I do know this, but I originally thought I was going to need parameters, then didn't, so I overlooked that. Thanks for pointing that out! :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use jQuery's 'live()' method to add event listeners to current and future nodes.

```
$(".month-selector").live('change', function(){
    setStones();
});
```

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for. I will mark you correct in 12 minutes when the time allotment ends.

Comment: What is the downside of the live method? I'm guessing some additional overhead as jquery has to watch the DOM for new nodes to appear?

Comment: @RedWolves I am using 1.4 :) .. Still good info though for others who may come across this.

Comment: The idea behind it is to create a kind of global listener with built-in conditionals that test which trigger fired the event and then looks to see if any custom events should fire.  In my experience, it's usually got a much lighter footprint than adding listeners to individual elements.

Comment: Live's deprecated do something like this:

`$('body').on('change', '.month-selector', function() {
   setStones();
});`

Answer (score 2):

That was super helpful! However, on in case you are adding an input event after the DOM has loaded you will need to use the "click" event to get it to work:

```
  $("input#thename").live("click", function(event) {
// handler for what should happen when somebody clicks on the new input field, in this case I needed a datepicker to pop up so lets get that fired. Now that the click element registered the new input object with the DOM, it can be used like a normal jQuery selector!
    $("input#thename").datepicker();
    });
```

Comment: but for some reason I have to click twice on the input box to get the datepicker to show up... any ideas on how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$(".month-selector").live("change", function(event) {
 // some code
});
```